# Duplicate TableViews that share same models

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I've got a situation in JavaFX where there will be identical TableViews in different parts of the app.

I want any changes in one table to reflect in any other.

Is it safe to just share same objects on all duplicate tables? i.e. selection models, data lists, cell factories and cell value factories?

Comment: cell and call value factories are just the way on how the data is taken and shown, you can have different ones, you just need to share the ObservableList

Comment: There is little danger to sharing the same `TableView` itself, as all of its properties will be shared as well, including the underlying `ObservableList` and cell/value factories. Just be aware if changes can be made in both tables at the same time, you'll need to determine which change "wins" and gets committed to the data model.

Comment: Yes I was wondering if I could actually share the tableview itself. I can make sure won't be accessible at same time. On different tabs representing different stages in a process.

Comment: You cannot share the literal `TableView` control in different views at the same time because a `Node` is allowed only one `Parent`. "_If a program adds a child node to a Parent (including Group, Region, etc) and that node is already a child of a different Parent or the root of a Scene, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from its former parent_" - [`javafx.scene.Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)

Comment: What about if you add and remove it when switching tabs etc? Then it will only exist in one place at a time. Will that be OK?

Comment: So long as you only intend to use in in one place at a time, yes I believe that should be okay.

Comment: I tried this and all was fine except TitledPane which had a gotcha. setContent doesn't work unless you also setContent(null) on the other TitledPane. The child doesn't automatically get removed from it's parent like it does with most components.